# Bug in: System.Web.UI.Page.InitOutputCache() or in System.Web.Mvc?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, http-headers

I'm using asp.net MVC with output caching (the OutputCache attribute) on some of my controller methods and am getting some really weird results in the HTTP headers.

When I add the attribute to the controller action that handles the main page view. the following header is produced:

```
Date                    Thu, 16 Jul 2009 23:04:58 GMT
Server                  Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By            ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version        2.0.50727
X-AspNetMvc-Version     1.0
Content-Encoding        gzip
Cache-Control           public, max-age=300
Expires                 Thu, 16 Jul 2009 23:04:59 GMT   <<<<<<<<< This is wrong
Last-Modified           Thu, 16 Jul 2009 23:04:55 GMT
Vary                    *
Content-Type            text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length          575
```

But when I add it to the controller action that renders a FileStreamResult result that sends down an image for that page, I get the following

```
Connection           close
Date                 Thu, 16 Jul 2009 23:04:59 GMT
Server               Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By         ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version     2.0.50727
Cache-Control        public, max-age=300
Expires              Thu, 16 Jul 2009 23:09:58 GMT      <<<<<<<<< This is right
Last-Modified        Thu, 16 Jul 2009 23:04:58 GMT
Vary                 *
```

You will note that there is a difference in the way that the Expires & Last-Modified is treated between the main page request and the image request.

To my minds eye the image one is correct because the Expires header is Last-Modified + max-age, but in the main page request, the Expires header is the same as the Last-Modified. I need both to be Last-Modified + max-age...

Whats gone wrong here, is it a bug somewhere??

Cheers
Anthony

Comment: Just a wild guess, but one is 5 seconds and one is 5 minutes. Seems like a parameter problem, no?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think so because it is reading the max-age correctly (see its set to 300 which is the value of the profile that I have setup).

Comment: I am seeing a similar problem.  The action filter seems to set Expires incorrectly.  In my case, it's a max of 24 hours from the request.